# Python: Limiting the size of a json string for posting to a server

Tags: python, json, post

I'm posting hundreds of thousands of JSON records to a server that has a MAX data upload limit of 1MB.  My records can be of very variable size, from as little as a few hundred bytes, to a few hundred thousand.

```
def checkSize(payload):
    return len(payload) >= bytesPerMB 


toSend = []
for row in rows:
    toSend.append(row)
    postData = json.dumps(toSend)
    tooBig = tooBig or checkSize()
    if tooBig:
          sendToServer(postData)
```

Which then posts to the server.  It currently works, but the constant dumping of toSend to a jsonified string seems really heavy and almost 100% too much, although I can't seem to find a way to do it another.  Would I be ok with stringifying the individual new records and keeping a tally of what they would be together?

I'm sure there must be a cleaner way of doing this, but I just don't know.

Thanks for any and all help given.

---

This is the answer I'm now using, I came up with it at the same time as @rsegal below, just posting for clarity and completion (sendToServer is just a dummy function to show things are working correctly),

```
import pickle
import json

f = open("userProfiles")
rows = pickle.load(f)
f.close()

bytesPerMB = 1024 * 1024
comma = ","
appendSize = len(comma)

def sendToServer(obj):
    #send to server
    pass

def checkSize(numBytes):
    return numBytes >= bytesPerMB

def jsonDump(obj):
    return json.dumps(obj, separators=(comma, ":"))

leftover = []
numRows = len(rows)
rowsSent = 0

while len(rows) > 0:
    toSend = leftover[:]
    toSendSize = len( jsonDump(toSend) )
    leftover = []
    first = len(toSend) == 0

    while True:
        try:
            row = rows.pop()
        except IndexError:
            break

        rowSize = len( jsonDump(row) ) + (0 if first else appendSize)
        first = False

        if checkSize(toSendSize + rowSize):
            leftover.append(row)
            break

        toSend.append(row)
        toSendSize += rowSize

    rowsSent += len(toSend)
    postData = jsonDump(toSend)
    print "assuming to send '{0}' bytes, actual size '{1}'. rows sent {2}, total {3}".format(toSendSize, len(postData), rowsSent, numRows)
    sendToServer(postData)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would do something like the following:

```
toSend = []
toSendLength = 0
for row in rows:
    tentativeLength = len(json.dumps(row))
    if tentativeLength > bytesPerMB:
        parsingBehavior # do something about lolhuge files
    elif toSendLength + tentativeLength > bytesPerMB: # it would be too large
        sendToServer(json.dumps(toSend)) # don't exceed limit; send now
        toSend = [row] # refresh for next round - and we know it fits!
        toSendLength = tentativeLength
    else: # otherwise, it wont be too long, so add it in
        toSend.append(row)
        toSendLength += tentative
sentToServer(json.dumps(toSend)) # if it finishes below the limit
```

The issue with your solution is that it's not great from a Big-O perspective. Mine runs in linear time, yours would run in quadratic time, because you're checking the cumulative length every loop. Resetting postData every time isn't very efficient, either.

Comment: HA!  While playing around, I pretty much got to nearly the exact same solution.  I have a 'leftover' list that takes anything that would send the size over the limit and the 'toSendLength' should be 'len(json.dumps(toSend)) - len(", ")' and the 'tentativeLength' should be 'len(json.dumps(row)) + len(", ") because with each new row, a comma and space will be added too.  Thanks rsegal!

Comment: And actually on top of that, I've added "separators=(',', ':')" to both json dumps saving a good bit more precious data!

Comment: Glad that worked out for you! You clearly know more than me about the specifics of Python's dealings with JSON. You seem to be making progress again, and maybe this will help someone in the future. Supercool!